# DatePicker MUI how to display "Clear" text on the left side of the calendar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have `DesktopDatePicker` from material-ui(version 5.0.0) and like to display "Clear" text on the left side of the calendar.

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";

export default function ResponsiveDatePickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(dayjs("2022-04-07"));

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        label="For desktop"
        value={value}
        minDate={dayjs("2017-01-01")}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        componentsProps={{
          actionBar: { actions: ["clear"], position: "left" }
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I added `position:"left"` in `actionBar` but this didn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is justified by a flexbox, you will need to add `justifyContent: "flex-start"` to your action bar style properties.

eg:

```js
componentsProps={{
   actionBar: { actions: ["clear"], style: {justifyContent: "flex-start"} }
}}
```

To further answer the question in the comment, since MUI components all give you access to styling I tried it and it worked - this is the MUIv4 way to access styling and it appears that it still works.  The MUIv5 way to do it would likely be to access styling through the `sx` property that the components now have.

```js
componentsProps={{
   actionBar: { actions: ["clear"], sx: {justifyContent: "flex-start"} }
}}
```

All MUI components give access to styling with the `sx` [property](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#1-one-off-customization).

Comment: This worked. Thank you! where can I find available props for `actionBar`? I know this official doc says there are other types of actions but they didn't say `style` is available for `actionsBar`.  https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/#action-bar